# ASP.NET Core 7 remove https

Tags: asp.net, http, https

After publishing my ASP.NET Core 7 Web API, I launch the debugging mode again (F5) but Visual Studio 2022 asked me to install a certificate (?). Now my source force the API in https... how can I remove https?

I don't see `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` in `program.cs` and in `launchsettings.json` I have

```
"applicationUrl": "https://localhost:45457;http://localhost:45458"
```

- I tried to remove `https://localhost:45457;` but that had no effect.
- I tried to remove the entire `"applicationUrl": "https://localhost:45457;http://localhost:45458"` line, then the API starts on `https://localhost:5001/index.html`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-7.0